# Android Navigation Drawer Menu should open When App Starts

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

My Client Requirement is to open navigation menu when the app starts, but I can't change my code to do so...Here is my Code, Please give me any sample code or idea to make my code workable. Thanks is advance. 
https://github.com/shovonacbd/NavigationDrawer/blob/master/drawer

Answer (score 0):

```
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT)
```

Put this in your onCreate, after your drawer is initialized.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work in my emulator .. should I try into a mobile device??

Comment: You get it working yet? I'd try on anything you can, just to diagnose the problem. I can help you further, but I need some explanation of what you've tried.